# Understanding AsyncController in Playframework example project

Tags: java, playframework, akka

I am studying Playframework conceptions and what I have stuck with is `AsyncController` example that is stating the following description:

> This controller contains an action that demonstrates how to write simple asynchronous code in a controller. **It uses a timer to asynchronously delay** sending a response for 1 second.

I'm marking the problematic statement in bold here.

Here is the code of controller where I removed the methods' descriptions not to waste space here on the question page.

```
@Singleton
public class AsyncController extends Controller {

    private final ActorSystem actorSystem;
    private final ExecutionContextExecutor exec;

    @Inject
    public AsyncControllerSO(ActorSystem actorSystem, ExecutionContextExecutor exec) {
      this.actorSystem = actorSystem;
      this.exec = exec;
    }

    public CompletionStage<Result> message() {
        return getFutureMessage(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).thenApplyAsync(Results::ok, exec);
    }

    private CompletionStage<String> getFutureMessage(long time, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        actorSystem.scheduler().scheduleOnce(
            Duration.create(time, timeUnit),
            () -> future.complete("Hi!"),
            exec
        );
        return future;
    }

}
```

I do not understand why the example giving the intuition of asynchrony in PlayFramework emphasises the "timer to asynchronously delay" feature?

As per the [description of scheduleOnce](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/Scheduler.html#scheduleOnce(delay:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,runnable:Runnable)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):akka.actor.Cancellable) method:

> Schedules a Runnable to be run once with a delay, i.e. a **time period that has to pass before the runnable is executed**.

Doesn't the latter mean that the delay is being performing in the same thread as `message()` method runs and hence this cannot be considered as asynchrony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not getting into specifics of Akka or Play, the general idea about an asynchronous delay is that it doesn't block the thread, so something else can be done meanwhile. When you call `.thenApplyAsync`, you're setting a callback which will be executed on the result of the future when it's ready. So the scheduler knows what to do: schedule to run the future in 1 second, (if it has something else to do meanwhile, do it), once the future is ready, run the callback.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So in other words scheduler starts a separate thread where the time starts being counted?